# How to display multiple lines of subtitles that have overlapping time on Youtube?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I have 2 subtitle entries that look like this in the srt file

```
00:10:15,60 --> 00:10:18,00
- We're good here in the sun, right?

00:10:15,80 --> 00:10:18,00
- You need some sunscreen? I got a 70 here.
```

As you can see, they overlap in time. When I test the subtitles with my KMPlayer, the result is:

1. The first sub appears at sec 15,60 on the second line on the screen
2. The second sub appears at sec 15,80 on the first line on the screen. They both disappear at sec 18,00.
   [image]

When uploading them onto Youtube, in the Subtitles Edit window,  the first sub appears on the first line and the second sub appears on the second line of the screen, which is even better to read:
[image]

BUT in [the actual YT video](https://youtu.be/ldjYX8zfhoQ), the first sub appears at sec 15,60 and disappears right at sec 15,80 before the second sec appears, so the viewers could only see the second sub:
[image]

Is this a Youtube bug or somebody could show me how to fix this, please?

Comment: Have you tried asking on youtube forums?

Comment: Yes I did, but I got no answer there.